# LINQ Update query with Join condition

Tags: linq

trying to do LINQ Update query using join with on condition also And condition

**Following my SQL Query**

```
UPDATE tbl_gs_related_orders  
SET RelatedCOI = sop.ServiceOrderNo  
FROM tbl_service_order_progress sop   
JOIN tbl_gs_related_orders ro  ON sop.parentid = ro.RelatedOrderParentId  
AND ro.RelatedCOIIdentifier collate database_default = sop.InstanceIdentifier collate database_default 
WHERE ro.ParentId = @PARENTID  
AND ro.relatedorderparentid IS NOT NULL
```

**This Query i want to convert into LINQ SO following my update LINQ query but getting some error like "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect type inference failed in the call to join"**

```
   var updateQuery = (from c in ctxParser.TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_PROGRESS
                               join o in ctxParser.tbl_GS_Related_Orders on new { ParentId = c.ParentId, InstanceIdentifier = c.InstanceIdentifier }
                               equals new { RelatedOrderParentId = o.RelatedOrderParentId, RelatedCOIIdentifier = o.RelatedCOIIdentifier }
                               where ro.RelatedOrderParentId == sParentId && ro.RelatedOrderParentId != null
                               select new
                               {
                                   ServiceOrderNo = c.ServiceOrderNo,
                                   Order = o
                               });

            foreach (var item in updateQuery)
            {
                item.Order.RelatedCOI = item.ServiceOrderNo;
            }

            ctxParser.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same aliases when creating Anonymous type for equals clause:

```
from c in ctxParser.TBL_SERVICE_ORDER_PROGRESS
join o in ctxParser.tbl_GS_Related_Orders on new { ParentId = c.ParentId, InstanceIdentifier = c.InstanceIdentifier }
equals new { ParentId = o.RelatedOrderParentId, InstanceIdentifier = o.RelatedCOIIdentifier }
```